# allow users to design forms with choices

Tags: python, django, forms, multiple-choice

Let's say I have an app that's supposed to allow (fashion designers) to post a "Design with Customizations"

The wanted result in the template is like this :

Dress:
Please select material : 1- wool, 2-cotton, 3-cashmere (only one can be selected)

What colours would you like : black $10, blue, red, yellow (multiple selections)

I'd like to allow designers to add options with choices and decide if (customers) can select one choice (radio button group) or multiple choices (checkboxes) with extra charge and decide default ones...

** Models.py **

```
class Choice(models.Model):
# e.g red
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    extra_charge = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


class Option(models.Model):
# what colours?
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice)


class Dress(models.Model):
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Choice, related_name='Dress')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

I have been working on Django for a while now but I have no idea how to go about this....

Answer (score 0):

According to my idea, Your `Dress  Model` should not have an `option` field, also, you should create a `foreign key` called `dress # related to Dress Model` in your `Option Model`.
Each time when you need designers to add an option with choices, just show him `the form page created from Option Model`, I think this is your solution!

Comment: Your  `Choice Model` should have `option foreign key `, your  `Option ` should not have `choice foreign key`. I think child Model  should have `foreign key`  related to `Parent Model` , but your code is reverse!

Comment: And how do I allow designers to set a limit number of choices? and whether  customer can chose one or many?

Comment: 1.If you want designers to set a limit number of choices, there are many solutions, you can use javascript(jquery/react/angular) to control the `dress upload ` page, to let designers add/delete options and choices  dynamically;of course, Django Form can do this work so , but the page will be not so friendly if you use Django Form directly! 2. You should also add a field in your `Option Model`, which is just like `type=Model.IntegerFiled(choices=((0,"radio"),(1,"select"))...)`

Comment: I only know Django so if you could elaborate on how this can be done using forms it'd be great. Also the data need to be stored back in models so doing it with JS would be so much tougher

Comment: Here is my Django solution: In your view, you should implement: 1.if add a new dress, show the form created from `Dress Model`,2.atfer upload a dress, view function return the form created from `Option Model`, in this step,you can store `Dress ID` in form hidden input or in Url parameters or in session;3. after uploading a new option, view function return `form` created form `Choice Model`, in this step, you can store `Option ID` in form hidden input or in Your Url or in session

Comment: 4.after uploading a new choice , view function should return a page which contains 2 buttons:`add choice for current option button` and `add option for current dress button`!This is all!

Comment: What i need help with is how to allow designer to control with the option is radio or select

Comment: After your adding a field like `type=Model.IntegerFiled(choices=((0,"radio"),(1,"select"))..‌​.)`  in `Option Model`,designers can `conrtol with the option is radio or select`when they are creating a new option,because `Option form` will have a element to let them choose `Option type`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142193/discussion-between-djangoguy-and-nick).

Comment: making choice child to option and option child to dress wouldn't that force me to display each choice in different page?

Comment: Is the form of your front-end page create from dress model automatically?

Comment: I'm on my way home, l can chat with you 13 hours later, can you wait?

Comment: If i am understanding your question correctly the answer is no. The designer in his page creates a post which is basically a form for customers to fill up and customers fill up form in the customer page like (place order) page

Comment: If you haven't got an answer which you think it can solve your problem ,I can try to write this Django  code (containing model form view and template )and share it with you 13 hours later  .

Comment: That would be so generous of you. I am trying on my end and i will keep u updated..

Comment: I have written some codes, I have implemented some Model and Forms, In One Form(which will be called when consumer filling up and create radio or multiple-selects options dynamically), I think after you read my codes, your problem will be solved.So, how do I show my codes to you?

Comment: royalinmy@gmail.com this is my email I don't know if it's going to show...

Comment: I have sent you a mail, this mail contains an URL ,you can clone/download my codes from it.